# SQLite + ATTACH Database + CREATE TABLE

Tags: sqlite, create-table

In my app, I used ATTACH DATABASE to "merge" 2 databases and work on them. It works perfectly. No problem for SELECT / UPDATE / INSERT on tables on the 2 database files.

My question: How to specify which database file to use when I want to do a CREATE TABLE ?

```sql
CREATE TABLE caps (
    id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name_en VARCHAR,
    status INTEGER DEFAULT (1))
```

EDIT:
I attached my second database like that:

```c
self.database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:DATABASE_READ_SANDBOX_PATH]; 
[self.database executeUpdate:[NSString
    stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE '%@' AS db2",
    DATABASE_USER_SANDBOX_PATH]];
```

So the second database has a name (`db2`), but the first? And I want to add the table in the first.

Comment: It's for an iOS app ;) I added the attach line in my initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) says:

> Tables in an attached database can be referred to using the syntax *database-name.table-name*.
>   The database-names '`main`' and '`temp`' refer to the main database and the database used for temporary tables.

Thus:

```
CREATE TABLE main.caps(...)
CREATE TABLE db2.caps(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to create the table in db1. But I never name the first database "db1" in my code. How to do that ? Does the default database used is db1 if we do not specify it ?

Comment: @muqaddar: Yes; `main` is the _in SQL_ name of the database that you opened the main connection on.